# How to move specific column one row down?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have the following text file:

```
 Ca1     
      2.75766949          2.49500070          0.77962056
 Ca2     
      5.83334907          4.99000000          3.81528863
 Ca3     
      0.00000000         -0.00000000         22.02929701
 Ca4     
      0.81321980          2.49500070          6.85095669
 Ca5     
      3.88889938          4.99000000          9.88662475
 Ca6     
      6.96457896          2.49500070         12.92229282
 Ca7     
      1.94444969          4.99000000         15.95796089
```

I wonder if "Ca" column could move down 1 row to get:

```
 Ca1     2.75766949          2.49500070          0.77962056

 Ca2     5.83334907          4.99000000          3.81528863

 Ca3     0.00000000         -0.00000000         22.02929701

 Ca4     0.81321980          2.49500070          6.85095669

 Ca5     3.88889938          4.99000000          9.88662475

 Ca6     6.96457896          2.49500070         12.92229282

 Ca7     1.94444969          4.99000000         15.95796089
```

I tried something with

> awk

but, I found no solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you **really** want a blank line between every 2 lines of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR%2!=0{prev=$0;next} {print prev, $0}' yourfile
```

With `sed`:

```
sed 'N; s/\n//g' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner check the text (the  `Ca` pattern) instead of line number to join lines.

```
 awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/Ca/?"":RS)}' file
```

If you want to check the line number, change the `/Ca/?` into `NR%2?`

Comment: Good one, but I have more than Ca lines to move. Good to know as well.

Comment: @git - if in your real data you `have more than Ca lines to move` then you need to edit the sample input/output in your question to be more representative of your real data.

Comment: yeah, you are right, but I wanted to write down points at the end but not always they let me to do that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NF>1?"\n":"")}1' file
 Ca1           2.75766949          2.49500070          0.77962056
 Ca2           5.83334907          4.99000000          3.81528863
 Ca3           0.00000000         -0.00000000         22.02929701
 Ca4           0.81321980          2.49500070          6.85095669
 Ca5           3.88889938          4.99000000          9.88662475
 Ca6           6.96457896          2.49500070         12.92229282
 Ca7           1.94444969          4.99000000         15.95796089

$ awk '{ORS=(NF>1?"\n\n":"")}1' file
 Ca1           2.75766949          2.49500070          0.77962056

 Ca2           5.83334907          4.99000000          3.81528863

 Ca3           0.00000000         -0.00000000         22.02929701

 Ca4           0.81321980          2.49500070          6.85095669

 Ca5           3.88889938          4.99000000          9.88662475

 Ca6           6.96457896          2.49500070         12.92229282

 Ca7           1.94444969          4.99000000         15.95796089
```

Answer (score 0):

with empty line between

```
sed '/^Ca[0-9]/ {N;s/\(\n\)\(.*\)/\2\1/;}' YourFile
```

wihtout

```
sed '/^Ca[0-9]/ {N;s/\n//;}' YourFile
```